# Can anyone please explain why set is behaving like this with boolean in it?

Tags: python, set

[image: set]

Please explain the behavior of the set in the image. I know that set is unordered but where are the other elements from the set a & b ?

Comment: True is 1, so that will be reduced to True, since True appears first. In the first example, 1 appears before True, so 1 stays

Comment: True and False are both boolean literals, and support arithmetic and compatibility with int: True + True -> 2, 9 + False -> 9, ...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`True` and `1` are the same:

```
>>> True == 1
True
>>>
```

Since sets can't have duplicate values, it only takes the one that appears first.

You can see that if you convert `True` to `int`:

```
>>> int(True)
1
>>>
```

The output is `1`.

Comment: `True == 1` is the important bit. `int(True)` being 1 is irrelevant. If you did `int("1")` that would also give you 1.

Comment: @khelwood That is true! I was just feeding additional information to the OP